# How do I export templated classes from a dll without explicit specification?

Tags: c++, dll, templates

I have a dll that contains a templated class. Is there a way to export it without explicit specification?

Comment: what do you mean with 'explicit specification'? without instantiating the template?

Comment: Without saying: "template class MyTemplate<int>" and the like in the dll where I define the template.

Comment: And what do you mean by 'export'? The C++ keyword or exporting functions in a type library?

Comment: Exporting functions. As far as I know, "export" is not widely supported in compilers.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since the code for templates is usually in headers, you don't need to export the functions at all. That is, the library that is using the dll can instantiate the template.

This is the only way to give users the freedom to use any type with the template, but in a sense it's working against the way dlls are supposed to work.

Comment: Here's some documentation on how to export template classes:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/168958

Comment: except from vs6 which supports such thing.
That's why convertions from VS6 to VS10 can cause error for that

Comment: This is not up to date anymore, due to changes in C++11

Comment: @Ident Can you elaborate it?

Comment: @camino It has been a while, so I am not sure what I was referring to there but according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Explicit_instantiation you can do "extern template class|struct" for explicit instantiation declaration. Now how would that work without exporting functions?

Comment: @Ident Thanks for the link

Comment: @Laserallan The link is bad. I've found this article under name "HOWTO: Exporting STL Components Inside & Outside of a Class".

Answer (score 6):

Are you looking into exporting an instantiation of a template class through a dll? A class along the lines:

```
typedef std::vector<int> IntVec;
```

There is some discussion how to do this on:
[http://support.microsoft.com/kb/168958](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/168/Q168958/)

Another approach is to explicitly exporting each function you are interested in through a wrapper class working against this template instance. Then you won't clutter the dll with more symbols than you are actually interested in using.

Comment: The link is bad. I've found this article under name "HOWTO: Exporting STL Components Inside & Outside of a Class".

Answer (score 5):

When the compiler finds an instantiation of a template class, like MyTemplate<int>, then it generates the code for the template specialization.
For this reason, all the template code must be placed in an header file and included where you want to use it.
If you want to 'export' your template class, just place your code in an header file and include it where it's needed.

Answer (score 4):

In your export control file.

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    #ifdef XXXX_BUILD
        #define XXXX_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
        #define XXXX_EXTERN
    #else
        #define XXXX_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
        #define XXXX_EXTERN extern
    #endif
#else
    #define XXXX_EXPORT
    #define XXXX_EXTERN
#endif
```

where XXXX_BUILD is a symbol defined in your project.

To get your class exported.

```
XXXX_EXTERN template class XXXX_EXPORT YourClass<double>;
```

Where double is the type you want to instantiate the class with.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/168958/how-to-export-an-instantiation-of-a-standard-template-library-stl-clas

https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php?title=Microsoft_KB_Archive/168958

P.S.

Referencing a template class brings it into existence. In particular, space for the static variables is allocated for the DLL. When I tested this around 2018, without the extern, each DLL gets memory allocated for static variables separately for each DLL.

Exporting is done slightly differently for Unix and .so. You would normally use
#ifdef _WIN32
to separate out the code needed for Windows MSVC from other compilers. We used to do this at my old company, but I no longer have access to that code.

But you would need to achieve the same result, which is to get the compiler to use the static variables in the class from another DLL instead of creating static variables for each DLL.

You could argue that the export should tell the compiler to do this, and maybe the situation has changed since 2018.

Comment: Why `extern`, is it required?

Comment: I am not sure. XXXX_EXTERN template class XXXX_EXPORT YourClass<double>;     \
     typedef YourClass<double> YourDouble; Give me a moment to edit this further.

Comment: I'll get back to this later. Have to go to work.

Comment: It appears that the right solution is to declare the instantiaion `extern` in the header and `EXPORT` in the .cpp file. Then and only then does it work as expected, do not combine `extern` and `export` in one declaration. Also, the `extern` keyword is only valid in this context on Windows (or maybe only in MSVC, not sure), gives a compilation error on other platforms with clang and GCC.

Comment: Thanks. To clarify my previous comment. In the header when compiling the DLL itself: `extern template class MyClass<int>;`. When compiling other code that imports the DLL: `template class  __declspec(dllimport) MyClass<int>;` In a .cpp file somewhere inside the DLL:  `template class  __declspec(dllexport) MyClass<int>;`

Comment: Interestingly, it so happens that my DLL does not use this exported class anywhere inside the DLL itself. So only the external code sees it. And the external code does not see `extern`. And yet, it didn't work without `extern`, very odd. The only place that sees `extern` is the `dllexport` instantiation in the .cpp inside the DLL, whose only purpose is to create and export this instantiation. I don't quite understand what `extern` really does here.