# How to instantiate the template in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I want to export **template functions** from DLL. I know I can use template specialization method as following.
**func.hpp**
`/*declare*/`
`template<typename T>
DLL_EXPORTS T func(T para);`

`/*specialization*/`
`template<>
DLL_EXPORTS int func<int>(int para);`

**func.cpp**
`template<>
DLL_EXPORTS int func<int>(int para)

{return para;}`

If I use template specialization. I should rewrite the `func` code for every type. It's not a good solution. But this is the only way I can found from the `C++ Primer`.
I found another way occasionally from someone else's codes, as following.

**func.hpp**
`/*declare*/`
`template<typename T>
DLL_EXPORTS T func(T para);`

**func.cpp**
`template<typename T>
DLL_EXPORTS T func (T para)

{return para;}`

`/*Instantiation*/`
`template
DLL_EXPORTS int func<int>(int);`
He use `template DLL_EXPORTS int func<int>(int)` to instantiate the template. you can't add `<>` after the keyword `template`. This way also works on class template.

**My question**: I can't find the way in the book. So I'm afraid  that it'll not work sometimes.  **Is it supported by the C++ standard?**

Comment: duplicate of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/362822/1354100) maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it called *explicit instantiation* See 14.7.2 of the C++11 standard (sorry I have no C++03 nearby).

You may instantiate in your translation unit as much as you wish instances of your template w/ any types you want, and this code will be placed into your DLL. And everything else just wouldn't.

Comment: which is the oldest C++ standard to support explicit instantiation