# dllexport function with templates (C++)

Tags: c++, templates, dll

I would like to know whether it is possible to define a templated dllexport function. Until now the function was not templated, and it is working properly. The code was this:

module.cpp:

```
#if defined(__cplusplus)
    #define DLL_Export extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#else /* __cplusplus */
    #define DLL_Export __declspec(dllexport)
#endif /* __cplusplus */
...
VirtualTPM * virtual_tpm;
...
DLL_Export void TestPointModule_Check(string name, void * value){
    virtual_tpm->CheckTestPoint(name, value);   
}
```

However, I need to extend the TestPointModule_Check function to manage other datatypes, so I created a templated CheckTestPoint(...) function, and I tried this:

module.cpp:

```
...
template <typename T>
DLL_Export void TestPointModule_Check(string name, void * value){
    virtual_tpm->CheckTestPoint<T>(name, value);    
}
```

but this gives me the following error: error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition

The `VirtualTPM::CheckTestPoint<T>` is correctly defined, since I can call a `virtual_tpm->CheckTestPoint<int>(name, value);` without errors.

Is there a possible way to do what I need? I would be able to restrict the template to 4 different datatypes (in fact, I did this when defining the template for the `VirtualTPM::CheckTestPoint<T>` function, but I don´t know how to do it.

Comment: You cannot do for unknown types, but it will work for particular specializations.

Comment: I am lost now, can you give me a brief example of how to do it with specializations?

Comment: I've put what I think that could work into an additional answer.

Answer (score 6):

Templated functions does not exist until they are instantiated. So that means that you can export only its instances not the template itself.

But you if you put the template definition in a header you can normally use it in other projects - same as you would do for header-only libs.

**Edit:**
Untested sample (this should export the function from DLL):

module.h:

```
template <typename T>
DLL_Export void TestPointModule_Check(string name, T * value);
```

module.cpp:

```
template <typename T>
DLL_Export void TestPointModule_Check(string name, T * value){
  virtual_tpm->CheckTestPoint<T>(name, value);    
}

// explicit instantiation
template void TestPointModule_Check<SomeType>(string name, SomeType * value);
```

Comment: I do not get very well what you are saying, can you give me a brief example of how to do it?

Comment: Even if you have a compiler that allows you to put the `dllexport` on the template definition, you don't want to do that, because that's a guarantee you can't make to your clients. They might try to instantiate on a type upon which you haven't instantiated in your library, and then they'll get linker errors.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure whether the other answers work, but I could not make them work. This is what should be done, with an example (the function template can generalize to any kind of template function):

In `*.hpp`:

```
template <typename T>
int randomFunction(T templateElement);
```

In `*.cpp`:

```
template <typename T>
int randomFunction(T templateElement)
{
    // code...
}
template DLL_EXPORT_IMPORT int randomFunction(float templateElement);
template DLL_EXPORT_IMPORT int randomFunction(double templateElement);
// Any other types you wanna implement...
```

And where `DLL_EXPORT_IMPORT` should be defined once in your library as something like:

```
#ifndef _WIN32
    #define DLL_EXPORT_IMPORT
#elif defined OP_EXPORTS
    #define DLL_EXPORT_IMPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLL_EXPORT_IMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

Comment: `DLL_EXPORT_IMPORT` seems to be useless in your case: `template __declspec(dllexport) int randomFunction(float templateElement)` will always work. I guess, you've missed a kind of `extern template int randomFunction(float templateElement)` in the header.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what [@Jhonny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1772573/johny) already pointed out You should be able to say:

```
...
template <>
DLL_Export void TestPointModule_Check<AParticularType>
                    (string name, AParticularType* value) {
    virtual_tpm->CheckTestPoint<AParticularType>(name, value);  
}
```

Put to header:

```
template<typename T>
void TestPointModule_Check(string name, T* value);
```

and:

```
template <>
DLL_Export void TestPointModule_Check<AParticularType>
                    (string name, AParticularType* value);
```

Also overwork your macro definitions to export from c++:

```
#if !defined(__cplusplus)
//  ^ Note
#define DLL_Export extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#else /* __cplusplus */
#define DLL_Export __declspec(dllexport)
#endif /* __cplusplus */
```

To find additional information about the topic refer to this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/168958) or this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362822/how-do-i-export-templated-classes-from-a-dll-without-explicit-specification).

Comment: Hi @g-makulik. It is strange but if I do this in the header file: `template <>
DLL_Export void TestPointModule_Check<int>(string name, void * value);` and this in the cpp:`template <>
DLL_Export void TestPointModule_Check<int>(string name, void * value){
    virtual_tpm->CheckTestPoint<int>(name, value);    
}` I get the same error in the header file (error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition)

Comment: @Iban What's the point of `T` btw, if you're using `void*` everywhere?

Comment: Well you are right, it should be `TestPointModule_Check<int>(string name, T* value)`, now I defined the function as void * value just to focus in the error I am getting and avoid errors such as "T is not defined" and bla bla bla. But it is just for debugging

Comment: your latest example is not working either, I get the error every time I type `template <> DLL_Export...`

Comment: @Iban For export of C++ functions omit the `extern "C"` when defining the `DLL_Export` macro.

Comment: Thanks to your last comment, now it builds correctly. However, it does not work properly yet. From my cpp code I access that function of the DLL using `askTpModulePtr = (Ask_TPModule)GetProcAddress(dllHandle, "TestPointModule_Check");` `assert(askTpModulePtr != NULL);`, where AskTPModule is defined as `typedef void * (__cdecl *Ask_TPModule)(string, bool, const ttm_dt_rn *, void *);` However, this assertion gives an error now. How can I call the function from the cpp file is the dllexport is not defined as extern "C"?

Comment: I think so, you should be able to do so, as long using C++ to compile. `"TestPointModule_Check"` is probably wrong. IMHO it should rather be s.th. like `"TestPointModule_Check<AParticularType>"`. I'm not really experienced with this, but there are tools available to inspect what's actually exported from the DLL.

Comment: I guess TestPointModule_Check is correct (or at least could be ok), since I get the same assertion error with other functions defined in the DLL, which have not been modified, and it is due to that omission of the `èxtern "C"` in the dll macro. I am almost a newbe in C++ and the code was written by another programmer, so I am lost with this... Thanks anyway, I will look for another solution

Comment: At least I'm happy to have helped solving the primary problems you were giving in your question.