My C++ Logger implementation doesn't seem to work
So, I want to get the console log to a file; that works fine, the problem lies when I tried to extend it to allow more inputs, and I don't seem to know why.
Engine.h:
#pragma once

#ifdef ENGINE_EXPORTS
#define ENGINE_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define ENGINE_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

// Logging functions
template <typename T, typename... Args>
ENGINE_API void EngineLog(const T& first, const Args&... args); // this started causing problems.

// Other unrelated functions

^ This is how I am handeling my header file.
In the Engine.cpp file; this is the function that does the logging:
//top of Engine:
#include "Engine.h"
template <typename T, typename... Args>
void EngineLog(const T& first, const Args&... args) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << first;
    ((oss << ' ' << args), ...);
    std::string strMessage = oss.str();
    std::cout << strMessage << std::endl;
    if (log_file.is_open()) {
        log_file << strMessage << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Failed to log to file." << std::endl;
    }
}

I tried anything that came to mind when it came to fixing this, but I never managed to find why it wouldn't compile, I hope this is obvious enough for anyone to help as this had me stumped for a while, and I would like to learn what I did wrong so I can never make the mistake again.
Maybe, there is a better way of doing dlls, but I am unaware of any other way...
Anyways; I Expect it to work in the Application project as follows:
EngineLog(38," <-- Numbers --> ", double, " ", integer);
Before I tried to expand it to accept arguments, it worked fine.
and I don't know if it was something I tried to do, but I started getting errors in other functions in the Engine.h, about my "nested create directory" script accepting strings being invalid, but I can always just change that, that is unrelated to my current problem.

The template code has to be in the header...

Please post [mre] including caller of EngineLog. @ChristianStieber's comment might be the answer.

@JesperJuhl I am using Visual Studio Community 2022's compiler, and when I remove ether, it just causes more errors...  This is super hard to explain, I only started using C++ around 6 months ago and I'm aiming to learn as much as possible.

@Kjajidlah You cannot solve every error together. Create a fresh simple enough project or even a single file to check what goes wrong. https://godbolt.org/ is a good start.

@ChristianStieber When removing it from the cpp file, it doesn't work at all.

@JesperJuhl OKay, I'll learn why, can you provide documentation?  Because my goal is to learn what I'm doing wrong, and I'm not getting much of that.

https://godbolt.org/z/rd3zYvP9G seems working fine in single file. If you still have issue, please include caller code.

Using your caller code EngineLog(38," <-- Numbers --> ", 0.0, " ", 1); is also working fine. https://godbolt.org/z/jKnrh7e5a Unless double and integer are variables

@LouisGo Okay, I am sorry but I am new to this website, how can I share more code?  Do I edit my question?

@Kjajidlah, on the top right of godbolt UI, you will see a share then click to share either short/long link. Make sure you reproduced your question in godbolt and update the question here. (Sometimes you will find out the error on your own while making [mre]). Then ask for reopen the question if you found there is no duplicate question.

@Kjajidlah the compiler needs to be able to see the code of a template top actually compile the template -- templates are glorified macros. There is not just one single compile for a template -- a new compile is made for every combination of parameter types. In theory (and I'm doing that on occasion) you can tell the compiler to produce compiled code for certain parameters and keep that in a separate object file; as long as only these parameters are used it will work. Any parameters not covered by this will cause linker errors.

@ChristianStieber Thank you so much for this information the dll compiles, however, I can not use it with __declspec(dllimport), and using it outside of the dll doesn't allow me to.

Which really, brings me back to the beginning of the loop:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19684162/24735820
